# Sending "CC" and "BCC" in substitution data when calling Node SparkPost API

Tags: javascript, node.js, sparkpost

I have templates created in SparkPost dashboard. But the problem I face is that I am not able to send "CC" or "BCC" by making the api calls. The code snippet below will help you understand what I am trying to do.

```js
var SPARKPOST_KEY = "KEY"
var sparkpost = require('sparkpost');
var sparkclient = new sparkpost(SPARKPOST_KEY);

var req_opts = {
 transmissionBody : {
  content: {
   template_id: 'order-confirmation',
   from: 'support@domain.in',
        subject: 'Order confirmation',
        headers: {
         "CC": "<anon2@gmail.com>"
        }
  },
  substitution_data: {
   "CC": "anon2@gmail.com",
   "customer": "Aravind",
   "order": 123532
  },
  recipients: [
        {address: {email:'anon1@domain1.in'}},
        {address: {email: 'anon2@gmail.com'}}
     ],
     "return_path": "support@domain.in",
 }
};

sparkclient.transmissions.send(req_opts, function(err, res){
 if(err){
  console.log("ERROR");
  console.log(err)
 }else {
  console.log(res.body);
  console.log("Mail has been successfully sent");
 }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the reply on your [github issue](https://github.com/SparkPost/node-sparkpost/issues/151), you must use either inline content or a template. So as the [documentation](https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/transmissions#header-using-a-stored-template) says, use just `template_id` in your `content`.

What needs to happen for this to work is that the `headers` in the template include a `CC` header, as described [here](https://support.sparkpost.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2432290-using-cc-and-bcc-with-the-rest-api?b_id=7411). Currently there is no way to set the headers of a template in the UI -- it must be done using the API.

To do this execute a PUT against the [templates endpoint](https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/templates#templates-update-put), in your case `https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/templates/order-confirmation`, with a JSON payload containing the following:

```
{
  "content": {
    <other content parts>
    "headers": {
      "CC": "{{CC}}"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you will also need to use the `header_to` parameter for your CC recipient to prevent their address showing up in the `To:` header. In your example this means replacing:

```
{address: {email: 'anon2@gmail.com'}}
```

with this:

```
{address: {email: 'anon2@gmail.com', header_to: 'anon1@domain1.in'}}
```

You also do not need the `return_path` parameter.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with templates. Its shooting an error  :                            `{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "required field is missing",
      "description": "At least one of 'text' or 'html' needs to exist in 'content'",
      "code": "1400"
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: Your template needs to include a `text` or an `html` part within `content`.

Comment: Why do I need to when there is no need for it ?

Comment: There is a need for it. Your message needs content.

Comment: Can you please give me a code example in the answer ? Because all of my contents are already in the templates

Comment: This is what I have in my JavaScript test code:
```var req_opts = {
  transmissionBody : {
    content: {
      template_id: '<my-template-id>'
    },
    substitution_data: {
      "CC": "<test_cc_address>"
    },
    recipients: [
          {address: {email: '<test_to_address>'}},
          {address: {email: '<test_cc_address>', header_to: '<test_to_address>'}}
      ]
  }
};
```
My template content has these fields: `from`, `headers`, `html`, and `subject`.

Comment: Also worth mentioning - if you issue a PUT to update a template property through the API because it isn't visible in the SparkPost admin UI and then later make a change to the template through the SparkPost admin UI, it doesn't overwrite the change you originally made through the API.